# JavaScript Self Invoking function properties

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand JS better, have a couple of clarifications. Lets suppose we have the following method

```
var customer = function(){
            var name = "Contoso";
            return {
                getName : function(){
                    return this.name;
                },
                setName : function(newName){
                    this.name = newName;
                }
            }
        }();
```

why is name not visible outside ?, when we log (customer.name) its undefined, however if we remove the self initializing parenthesis on function and change the variable declaration to (this.name) & again when we log the same we are able to see the value. what am i missing in here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take in consideration that JavaScript doesn't really have native classes. With this said, the way you can create constructors in order to "mimic" a class and be able to use `this` you need to create something like so:

```
function fnc (string) {
  this.string = string; 
}

fnc.prototype.getString = function() {
  return this.string;
}

var x = new fnc('bar');
console.log(x.getString()); //bar
```

This is called the Constructor Pattern. 
What you're trying to do is use something called the Module Pattern which works something like so:

```
var fn = (function() {
  var string = 'foo';
  return {
    getString() {
      return string;
    }
  }
})();

console.log(fn.getString()); //foo
```

Here is a working example: https://repl.it/FCn7

Also, a good read: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

**Edit**
Example using `getString` and `setString` with the Module Pattern

```
var fn = (function() {
  var string = 'foo';
  return {
    getString() {
      return string;
    },
    setString(str){
      string = str;
    }
  }
})();

fn.setString('xyz');
console.log(fn.getString()); // xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` is creating variable inside function scope which is not available outside as function property. If you want to access properties like `customer.name` you need to initialize it as `this.name` as you noticed.

`var` in this example is like creating private variable which can be modified by functions, but not directly.

SO this will work:

```
var customer = function(){
    var name = "Contoso";
    return {
        getName : function(){
            return name;
        },
        setName : function(newName){
            name = newName;
        }
    }
}();
```

Comment: second example won't work, since you define `name` on `this` but `return` a different object. If you want to use this function as a constructor, you'd have to define `this.getName = ...` or `customer.prototype.getName = ...` and remove the `return`. And you'd have to call the function with the `new` keyword; at the moment, `this` points to the global object, and `this.name` would be added to `window`

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. You are right. I removed the second example